# Darknet weight training 'Assertion '0' failed'

Tags: python, training-data, darknet

I've just started training my first weights. Transfer learning to be exact. The pc I have is running on Ubuntu and currently using Darknet  framework with the darknet53.conv.74 pre-trained model + yolov3.cfg that I modified for a single class - Human. However, after starting to train it returns me this error. Could the error be because I haven't made the test.txt file? (It's made, but empty)

*./darknet detector train training/obj.data training/yolo-obj.cfg training/darknet53.conv.74
yolo-obj
First section must be [net] or [network]: Success
darknet: ./src/utils.c:256: error: Assertion `0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)*

The line 256 of the utils.c is simply an error function:

```
void error(const char *s)
{
    perror(s);
    assert(0);
    exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code in plain text in your question. Also take a moment to improve your question with [ask]

Comment: What code do u wish to see? The .cfg file?

Comment: the code that could generate 
First section must be [net] or [network]: Success darknet: ./src/utils.c:256: error: Assertion `0' failed.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have a clue on which file/code is directly responsible for this. I followed this tutorial https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects and the error pops up after the ./darknet detector train training/obj.data training/yolo-obj.cfg training/darknet53.conv.73 command.

Comment: A lot of us get skilled by digging the code. My guess is you have very little chance anyone of us will do it for you. Maybe try to find an other tutorial to unblock your progress.

Comment: My intention wasn't for someone to find it for me, I just hoped that someone would point me in the direction I should search at. As this is the only error message I get, and from what I've gathered online, It usually happens with people that use GPU's and CUDA. I don't use any of those. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: If you are running on windows it may be this issue : https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/pull/476

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't include in the question. I'm using Linux.

Comment: Maybe try to edit config file to ensure you have proper line ending formating. I mean be sure to not have CR LF but only CR character at the end

Comment: Heeeey! You were right! It actually worked. All the spaces were CF and LF so it couldn't recognize it! Replaced it with only LF and it worked! Now i've got a different error, but I think I can figure this one out. Thanks, man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this [issue](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/pull/476) it may be cause by CR/LF in config file. For @legoloco it was the case. Reformatting line ending with only CR fix his issue.